# Getting Error When Opening Files

Tags: c, file-io, pocketc

I'm developing a simple Text Editor to understand better [PocketC](http://orbworks.com/pcce) language, then I've done this:

```
#include "\\Storage Card\\My Documents\\PocketC\\Parrot\\defines.pc"

int filehandle;
int file_len;
string file_mode;

initComponents()
{
    createctrl("EDIT", "test", 2, 1, 0, 24, 70, 25, TEXTBOX);
    wndshow(TEXTBOX, SW_SHOW);
    guigetfocus();
}

main()
{
    filehandle = fileopen(OpenFileDlg("Plain Text Files (*.txt)|*.txt; All Files (*.*)|*.*"), 0, FILE_READWRITE);
    file_len = filegetlen(filehandle);

    if(filehandle = -1)
    {
        MessageBox("File Could Not Be Found!", "Error", 3, 1);
    }

    initComponents();
    editset(TEXTBOX, fileread(filehandle, file_len));
}
```

Then I tried to run the application, it opens the Open File Dialog, I select a file(that is at `\test.txt`) that I've created with notepad, then I got my `MessageBox` saying that the file wans't found. Then I want to know why I'm getting this if the file is all correct?

*PS: When I click to exit the `MessageBox`, I saw that the `TextBox` is displaying where the file is(I've tested with many other files, and with all I got the error and this).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 if(filehandle = -1)
```

This should be

```
 if(filehandle == -1)
```